# Easiest way to rotate image in java

Tags: java, image

please how I can rotate image **easiest** way?

My Image:

```
 g.drawImage(image, x, y, this);
```

Comment: See here [Rotating images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639567/java-rotating-images).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Graphics2D g2d=(Graphics2D)g;       // Create a Java2D version of g.
g2d.translate(170, 0);              // Translate the center of our coordinates.
g2d.rotate(1);                      // Rotate the image by 1 radian.
g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 200, 200, this);
```

Source: [Rotate Image](http://beginwithjava.blogspot.in/2009/02/rotating-image-with-java.html)