# Rotating image issue

Tags: java, arrays, rotation, 2d

This is some code that I have written to rotate an image 90 degrees clockwise. This works fine when the image's height matches its width. But when this is not the case, the image has a black edge at the end where the rest of the image is supposed to be. Any help is appreciated

```
public void rotate(){
    int y = this.image.length;
    int x = this.image[0].length;
    int[][] rotate = new int[x][y];
    UI.println(y);
    UI.println(x);
    for(int row = 0; row<x/2; row++){
        for(int col = 0; col < ((y+1)/2); col++){
            int temp = this.image[row][col];
            rotate[row][col] = this.image[y-1-col][row];
            rotate[y-1-col][row] = this.image[y-1-row][y-1-col];
            rotate[y-1-row][y-1-col] = this.image[col][y-1-row];
            rotate[col][y-1-row] = temp;
        }
    }
    int[][] image = new int[x][y]; 
    this.image = rotate;
```

Comment: Possible dublicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639567/java-rotating-images

Comment: The question marked as duplicate is wrong. Here op wanted to program to rotate image. not to use any utility method provided by awt.

Comment: Im not sure you understand it - can you spin your head around it?

Answer (score 0):

Transformation matrix for rotation is

```
| c   -s  0 |
| s   c   0 |
| 0   0   1 |
```

*c = cos theta   and s = sin theta*
Transofromation matrix for translation is

```
| 1   0   xr |
| 0   1   yr |
| 0   0   1  |
```

You need translate translate center of object to origin
then rotate
then translate back

```
|1  0  xr|   |c  -s  0|   |1  0  -xr|   |x|
|0  1  yr| x |s  c   0| x |0  1  -yr| x |y|
|0  0  1 |   |0  0   1|   |0  0    1|   |1|
```

After solving it you will get

```
|x*c-y*s-xr*c+yr*s+xr|
|x*s+y*c-xr*s-yr*c+yr|
|          1         |
```

So new point (x2, y2) is such that

```
x2 = x*c-y*s-xr*c+yr*s+xr
y2 = x*s+y*c-xr*s-yr*c+yr
```

put c = 0  (*because cos90 = 0*)
and s = 1  (*because sin90 = 1*)

```
x2 = -y+yr+xr
y2 = x-xr+yr
```