# How can I rotate a matrix a clockwise?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, matrix

Here's an example:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

After rotating:

```
4 1 2
7 5 3
8 9 6
```

4x4 example:
1   2  3  4
5   6  7  8
9  10 11 12
13 14 15 16

5   1  2  3
9  10  6  4
13 11  7  8
14 15 16 12
5x5 is similar

I can rotate 90° but that's not true in this exercise
A element of the matrix just move once
I have tried for 2 hours to find the algorithm but my code doesn't work.
Please help me solve this problem

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void input(int **a,int row,int column)
{
    for(int i=0; i<row; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<column; j++)
            cin>>a[i][j];
    }
}

void output(int **a,int row,int column)
{
    for(int i=0; i<row; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<column; j++)
            cout<<a[i][j]<< " ";
        cout<<endl;
    }
}

void rotate(int **a,int **b,int m,int n)
{
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        int k=m-1;
        for(int j=0; j<m; j++)
        {
            b[i][j]=a[k][i];
            k--;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int m,n;
    cin>>m>>n;

    int **a=new int*[m];
    for(int i=0; i<m; i++)
        a[i]=new int[n];

    int **b=new int*[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        b[i]=new int[m];

    input(a,m,n);
    rotate(a,b,m,n);
    output(b,n,m);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: one idea is to do read the matrix spiral-wise and keep track of the last seen element and replace it with the current one and set the current as the last seen one.

Comment: Just write your algorithm on a piece of paper first, trying to think of all possible conditions, instead of jumping into code immediately. Example: each element in col==0 and row==x must be moved to col=0 and row=x-1 (except element in row==0); then, each element in row==0 and col==y must be moved to row=0 and col=y+1 (except element in the last column), etc ... and since this is C++ exercise, use `std::vector` instead of raw pointers.

Comment: can you show how a 4x4 or 5x5 matrix is supposed to be rorated? Also, is input always a square matrix or could be mxn, in which case, what is the expected output after rotation.

If you write enough examples, I'm sure there will arise a pattern which can be put into some kind of formula

Comment: Put your matrix on a coordinate plane and express the rotation in algebra. Then translate that to code.

Comment: +1: show example with a 4x4 or 5x5 matrix. Is a "unitary" rotation of one only position the only thing requested to do?

Comment: btw you can rotate matrix by any angle see [How can I rotate a 2d array by LESS than 90°, to the best approximation?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40585975/2521214)

Answer (score 1):

Although I didn't find some single mathematical formula for this rotation, I did it using four tiny loops.

Also my program supports any arbitrary size of matrix `NxM`, not only square, and not only odd sizes.

For simplicity of running following code snippet instead of reading matrix from `std::cin`, I inlined values of matrix elements as constant in code.

Also for simplicity I used `std::vector` not to do any `new`/`delete` operations of plain matrix. It is quite obvious how to adopt my solution to your case of plain array.

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/99sP3KfeM)

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

void output(auto const & a) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < a[i].size(); ++j)
            std::cout << std::setw(2) << a[i][j] << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

void rotate(auto & a) {
    int i_first = 0, i_last = a.size() - 1,
        j_first = 0, j_last = a[0].size() - 1;
    auto b = a;
    while (i_first <= i_last && j_first <= j_last) {
        for (int j = j_first + 1; j <= j_last; ++j)
            b[i_first][j] = a[i_first][j - 1];
        for (int i = i_first + 1; i <= i_last; ++i)
            b[i][j_last] = a[i - 1][j_last];
        for (int j = j_last - 1; j >= j_first; --j)
            b[i_last][j] = a[i_last][j + 1];
        for (int i = i_last - 1; i >= i_first; --i)
            b[i][j_first] = a[i + 1][j_first];
        ++i_first; --i_last;
        ++j_first; --j_last;
    }
    a = b;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> a = {
        { 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5},
        { 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11},
        {12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17},
        {18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23},
        {24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29},
    };
    std::cout << "Before:" << std::endl;
    output(a);
    rotate(a);
    std::cout << "After:" << std::endl;
    output(a);
}
```

Output:

```
Before:
 0  1  2  3  4  5 
 6  7  8  9 10 11 
12 13 14 15 16 17 
18 19 20 21 22 23 
24 25 26 27 28 29 

After:
 6  0  1  2  3  4 
12 13  7  8  9  5 
18 19 15 14 10 11 
24 20 21 22 16 17 
25 26 27 28 29 23
```